# How to find out if the copied text in the Clipboard contains header information?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have implemented Copy/Paste functionality in my WPF `DataGrid`. I want to copy text along with the headers. Now in the Paste function, I get the copied text through a `ClipboardHelper` class that returns me a List of string arrays. I remove the first item in the list because it includes the header information before pasting it in the grid. But when I copy from an Excel sheet I have to paste everything as I won't be copying the headers in excel. So how do I find out if the copied text contains header information / if the copied text is from inside the grid or outside?

```
List<string[]> rowData = ClipboardHelper.ParseClipboardData();
```

I have used this property to include headers

```
ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
```